# Am installing Xampp, the apache service in xampp is not getting installed properly

Tags: apache

Am installing Xampp, the apache service in xampp is not getting installed properly because of an error " port 80 or 443 is already in use". I dont have IIS or skype in my system. The process running at 443 is svchost, and i cant stop it and unable to fix the issue...pls help me

Answer (score 0):

probadly port 80 is used by SQL server reporting services, you should disable it, Run>services.msc> search for SQL server reporting services (MSSQLSERVER) and disable it, then restart your Xampp, hope this help! :)

Comment: No SQL server is running in my machine